# How can I track down the origins of a vague typescript error, Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'length'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

So I deleted my node modules, and ran yarn. And suddenly got this error:

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17687:13 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'length'.

17687 declare var length: number;
```

Even when checking out some previous commits, I have the same problem. Since the error doesnt give me much to go on, I am clueless. There is nog length var in my project.

node version 18.14
TS version : 4.9.4 and 4.8.4 (and also 4.7.4)
nestjs 8.0.4

I realize this is not much to go on, but if someone could give me a way to investigate further, or way to find where this length variable is being declared in another node module or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like two packages declare the same variable. Probably a version mismatch between typescripts

Answer (score 1):

After a very long debugging session I found the answer, it was the allowJs flag in the tsconfig.json that also parsed .js files that were copied into my dist folder.

Comment: You should probably exclude the dist folder